# Make a div toggle words by changing the text via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I click on the button, a class gets added, and the text changes from "Get in touch" to "Work." However, when I click the button again in its "work state," the text doesn't change back to "Get in touch." Why doesn't it work?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cLgkwjhb/

**HTML**

```
<a id="contact-button" href="#">Get in touch</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#contact-button {
    background: #000;
    background-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

**JS**

```
jQuery('#contact-button').click(function( e ){

    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).addClass('work-button').text('Work');

});

jQuery('#contact-button.work-button').click(function( e ){

    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).removeClass('work-button').text('Get in touch');

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than adding a class you could keep track of clicks, if the click count is divisible by `2`(`(c++ % 2 == 0)`), change the text to `Work` else `Get in touch`.

```js
var c = 0;
jQuery('#contact-button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery(this).text((c++ % 2 == 0) ? 'Work' : 'Get in touch');
});
```

```css
#contact-button {
  background: #000;
  background-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="contact-button" href="#">Get in touch</a>
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution but I need the class added because I plan on making some CSS changes later.

Comment: @J82 - If that is the case you could do it this way ----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLgkwjhb/3/).

Comment: Just one issue. I have it so that certain divs fade in and out depending on what state the button is in (i.e. work, get in touch). Using your method, if I click the `#contact-button` fast repeatedly, the divs fade in and out long after I stopped clicking to make up for the amount of times I clicked. Is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: @J82 - Could you create a Fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @J82 use `.stop()` before the animation/fade

Comment: @J82 - [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/tk1fjwq0/1/), the trick is to use [`.finish()`](http://api.jquery.com/finish/) and [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) on both `#primary` and `#contact-keebs`, before adding any further `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` animations.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLgkwjhb/1/)

```
    var work = false;
    jQuery('#contact-button').click(function( e ){

        e.preventDefault();
        work = !work;
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('work-button').text(work ? 'Work' : 'Get in touch');


    });
```

Basically use one event listener, because in your original, both functions are being called.

Comment: Professional solution!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work simply because  `#contact-button.work-button` doesn't exist when you set that click handler. Since you add the class later on, jQuery can't match any element with that selector by the time that line of code runs.

What you can do is use all the logic in a single click handler

```
jQuery('#contact-button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('work-button').text(function (i, text) {
        return text === 'Work' ? 'Get in touch' : 'Work';
    });
});
```

```js
jQuery('#contact-button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('work-button').text(function (i, text) {
        return text === 'Work' ? 'Get in touch' : 'Work';
    });
});
```

```css
#contact-button {
    background: #000;
    background-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="contact-button" href="#">Get in touch</a>
```

Or use a dynamic selector like `.on()` but that's not as elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :- http://jsfiddle.net/cLgkwjhb/5/

```
jQuery('#contact-button').click(function( e ){

    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('work-button');

    if ($(this).text() == "Work")
       $(this).text("Get in touch")
    else
       $(this).text("Work");

});
```